# How to extract a particular value from this json output

Tags: javascript, json, pubmed

I am trying to decode pubmed json output as follows.

1. https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=29753496&retmode=json
2. https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=15674886&retmode=json

How can I extract the doi from this output?

```
        "articleids": [
            {
                "idtype": "pubmed",
                "idtypen": 1,
                "value": "15674886"
            },
            {
                "idtype": "doi",
                "idtypen": 3,
                "value": "10.1002/14651858.CD001801.pub2"
            },
            {
                "idtype": "rid",
                "idtypen": 8,
                "value": "15674886"
            },
            {
                "idtype": "eid",
                "idtypen": 8,
                "value": "15674886"
            }
        ],
```

I was able to extract other details like title, author name etc. But this one seems little tricky.

Sorry if its a silly question.

Comment: `(articleids.filter(a => a.idtype === 'doi').pop() || {}).value`  assuming there is max one `idtype === 'doi'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, lets assume this is your whole JSON string.

```
var json = '{"articleids": [
    { "idtype": "pubmed", "idtypen": 1, "value": "15674886" },
    { "idtype": "doi", "idtypen": 3, "value": "10.1002/14651858.CD001801.pub2" },
    { "idtype": "rid", "idtypen": 8, "value": "15674886" },
    { "idtype": "eid", "idtypen": 8, "value": "15674886" }
]}';
```

Now we want to parse this and get it into an object.

```
var arr = JSON.parse(json);
```

To get a specific object based on the value of an item, we will want to use `.filter()`.  We'll use `.pop()` to return the first element of the returned array, which in this case should be the only object returned.

```
var doi = arr.articleids.filter(function(v)
{
    return v.idtype == "doi";
}).pop();
```

Variable `doi` is now going to hold the filtered object.

```
idtype: "doi"
idtypen: 3
value: "10.1002/14651858.CD001801.pub2"
```

Comment: Thanks Frax.  Didn't realize `$.parseJSON()` was deprecated as of JQuery 3.  They are now using it as an alias of `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: You're welcome :) Nice explanation, btw. However, you could use an arrow function for brevity and increased readability. I didn't add it to the edit cause it's a less obvious fix - the portability of old syntax is still a valid argument to keep it.

Comment: As far as I know, IE11 has no support for arrow functions, which is likely to be a reason to not use it for many at the moment.  Opinions may differ, but I know at my job, we have a lot of customers that still use IE10.  http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: Yep, true. However, one could use Babel or Closure Compiler to get both new syntax and portability. (I'm not saying you should change your answer, just spreading the word)

Comment: In case anyone may wonder what alternative we're talking about here.  Here's an example using the above code.  This would replace where we're setting variable doi.  `var doi = arr.articleids.filter(v => v.idtype == "doi").pop();`

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas and @Frax for your help. The code worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var jsonObj = {
 "articleids": [{
   "idtype": "pubmed",
   "idtypen": 1,
   "value": "15674886"
  },
  {
   "idtype": "doi",
   "idtypen": 3,
   "value": "10.1002/14651858.CD001801.pub2"
  },
  {
   "idtype": "rid",
   "idtypen": 8,
   "value": "15674886"
  },
  {
   "idtype": "eid",
   "idtypen": 8,
   "value": "15674886"
  }
 ]
};

var res = jsonObj.articleids.filter(obj => obj.idtype == 'doi');

console.log(res[0]); // {idtype: "doi", idtypen: 3, value: "10.1002/14651858.CD001801.pub2"}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rohit. I used the answer by Thomas above.

Answer (score -1):

In your example, the value "doi" can be referenced as:

`articleids[1].idtype`

Here's an example you can use yourself.

*note: I'm wrapping your data structure in an object called `obj`*

```
var obj = {
    "articleids": [{
        "idtype": "pubmed",
        "idtypen": 1,
        "value": "15674886"
    }, {
        "idtype": "doi",
        "idtypen": 3,
        "value": "10.1002/14651858.CD001801.pub2"
    }, {
        "idtype": "rid",
        "idtypen": 8,
        "value": "15674886"
    }, {
        "idtype": "eid",
        "idtypen": 8,
        "value": "15674886"
    }]
}

//access doi
obj.articleids[1].idtype // -> 'doi'

//loop throigh idTypes and log them to the console
obj.articleids.forEach(function(article) {
    console.log(article.idtype)
})
```

JSON allows you to access keys in [brackets] but you can also use the '.' property accessor when you have a string as the object key. Given:

`var me = {"name":"AK"}`

**AK** can be referenced as

`me["name"]`

or

`me.name`

Comment: You're assuming `articleids` has a member with `idtype === 'doi'` and it's always the 2nd element.

Comment: i now see the err of my answer.